# Moving files to different locations depending on number chosen

Tags: windows, copy, move

I have TONS and TONS of files I need to move/copy around in Win 10 - what I would like is to highlight a file(s) and press 1 to send to Pictures, 2 to Documents etc.

I am looking for a complete solution rather than a bite of code I would not know how to use - any ideas?

I've researched off and on for years and not found anything that does what I want - I am not a programmer so ... any direction/help/guidance would be appreciated.